# return value using into another function

Tags: python, function, return

I am using return value of function into another function, I want to do first I check if function return value ? if yes then only use return value
I am able to do this but in my case function call two times reason also i know but how can I achieve it with function call for only one time

Actually I am new in programming please can anyone help me 
Thank you in advance

```py
from loginAuth import *

class DisplayInfo:
    def displayInfo(self):
        # create object of loginAuth class
        obj = LoginAuth()
        if obj.check_password_and_userid():
            userid, userrole = obj.check_password_and_userid()
            print(userid,userrole)

obj = DisplayInfo()
obj.displayInfo()
```

here method: check_password_and_userid() is a function of class LoginAuth
which return userid and userrole

output : 01 Admin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

obj.check_password and userid() returns a tuple like (userid, user role) if it's true then you can just set data to a variable then play with the data.

```
from loginAuth import *

class DisplayInfo:
    def displayInfo(self):
        # create object of loginAuth class
        obj = LoginAuth()
        data = obj.check_password_and_userid()
        if data:
            userid, userrole = data
            print(userid,userrole)

obj = DisplayInfo()
obj.displayInfo()
```